# How to Use Python to execute initial commands over the terminal and then continue use

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh

I have looked into using pxssh ,subprocess and paramiko but have found no success. What I am ultimately trying to do is figure out a way to not only use SSH to access a server and execute commands using a python script and finish there, but also have it open an instance of the terminal after executing all the commands for continued use.

Currently the server has modules that clients have to manually activate using commands after they have established an SSH connection.

For example:

module python

This command would give the user access to python.

Following this the user would then be able to use python and all its commands through the ssh connection in the terminal.

The issue I have with the methods listed earlier for executing these commands is that it does not display an instance of the terminal. It successfully executes the commands but since these commands have to be executed every time a new SSH connection is established it's worthless unless I can get essentially a copy of the terminal that the Python script executed and loaded up all the modules with.

Does any one have a solution to this? I've scoured the web for hours to no success.

This is a very difficult issue to explain so if anything is unclear please ask me and I will try my best to rephrase things. I am very new to all this.

Comment: If you used heroku with django, this sounds like what happens when you do heroku run python manage.py shell.  This sounds like a question better suited on super-user than here as I don't believe there's any real programming necessary.  See e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/306530/run-remote-ssh-command-with-full-login-shell, unless I'm completely missing what you're looking for.

Comment: So you just want to build a wrapper around SSH, that would execute a few commands before letting the user use the shell prompt?

Comment: @thkala That is pretty much what I am trying to do in a nutshell.

Comment: @StevenOL: any reason for not just adding the `module` command in the remote user's `.bashrc` file?

Comment: @thkala This is going to be used by researchers and there are over 800 of them. I want to create an interface that they can use to select all the programs they want standard on their account whenever they ssh. Store that in a text file or something. Run an application on their end that would then automatically load all those modules up for them after they SSH in... Not really sure what the .bashrc file is either though. I'll look at it.